# Multiple instances of a background task with an ApplicationTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I've registered a background task with an `ApplicationTrigger` trigger to handle my download logic in the background. This technically works, but only for one download at a time.

After registering the in-process background task, I'm calling this method:

```
public async void StartNew(DownloadTask task)
{
    DownloadTasks.Insert(0, task);
    await (App.DownloadBackgroundTask.Trigger as ApplicationTrigger).RequestAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Collections.ValueSet()
    {
        { "dl", 0 }
    });
}
```

This method calls `OnBackgroundActivated` for the first file just fine, but subsequent times this call seems to be getting ignored.

```
protected async override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    var d = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
    if (args.TaskInstance == null)
        return;
    var name = args.TaskInstance.Task.Name;
    if(name == DownloadBackgroundTask.Name)
    {
        var id = (int)(args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as ApplicationTriggerDetails).Arguments["dl"];
        var dlTask = DownloadManager.DownloadTasks[id];
        await dlTask.Execute();
    }
    d.Complete();
}
```

Is this type of solution not designed for multiple instances? What would be a better way to handle this type of situation?

Is there anything I'm missing here, or is that a wrong approach alltogether?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is system defualt class to handle background downloading named `BackgroundDownloader`. [BackgroundDownloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader) handles download queue so it can download multiple files at a time. You can fetch the current download queue using `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()`.

```
Uri source = new Uri(serverAddressField.Text.Trim());
string destination = fileNameField.Text.Trim();
StorageFile destinationFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
                    destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);
```

//Download Progress

```
 private void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation download)
        {
             double percent = 100;
            if (download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
            {
                percent = download.Progress.BytesReceived * 100 / download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
            }           
        }
```

Comment: My situation is a bit more complex, as sometimes I need to download separate streams (video and audio) and then merge them afterwards, while keeping the UI up to date with what is going on in the background. Can this class be used for more complex operations?

Comment: Yes you can download create downloads for seperate streams for audio and video and download them in LocalFolder. After that merge them into user requested folder. You can show the combined download time for audio and video to notify user.

Comment: How do I keep the entire media processing logic in the background as well?